# Custom link target in sxa

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, links

I was trying to insert an external  link . In link target there was an option in target is `custom`.

What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set different types of `targets` on an `anchor tag`. Here is this list.

[image]

So if you select custom, then you can specify these `targets` in the `custom textbox` (that enables once you select custom) and it will appear in the `_target` attribute of anchor.

Read more here

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Hope this will help.